# Building abs and shaping up muscles

Tags: workout-routines, strength, muscle, workout, abdominals

I have been working out since 3 months. Initially, my aim was to increase weight. I increased my weight by 3 kgs during this time.

Now I feel confident and comfortable lifting moderately heavy weights. So, I want to shift my focus in giving my body a good muscular build.

Presently my workout is of 6 days a week. I workout for 1 hr. My weight is 59 kg and height is 175 cms. Workout basically consists of each body part each day; warmups included.

I want to ask, whether to get a more muscular look, do I have to include anything else in my routine? I also want to ramp up my exercises to achieve my goal. In what direction should I spend my energy - exercise, now?

Comment: "Do I have to include anything else in my routine?" No idea, you haven't told us what your routine consists of right now other than "each body part each day".

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your weight and height I can tell you right now you will need to focus on what you eat. You need to create a bulking diet(I just answered that question here: [Bulking diet](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13599/do-i-really-have-to-eat-this-much-for-building-muscles))

While the workout itself is important diet is still 80%-90% of progress. There are so many good routines by doing a quick Google search that I see no need to repeat one here. Just get your diet right and the rest will follow.