Protein intake relative to lean body weight
Background

72 years old chronologically
54 years old functionally (by a number of tests)
Height 5'9.5"
Mesomorph

Withings scale measurements

Weight 197 lbs
Body fat 17.1%
Lean mass 79.3%

Training|conditioning

Whole-body EMS training 20 min 2X / week
Mobility work
Timed static contractions (Dead lift, squat, press, shoulder shrug) 2X / week
10k+ brisk steps per day

Goal
I'd like to drop body fat.  I don't really care about what weight I end up at - more interested in getting leaner.
To do this I'd like to dial in my protein intake to maintain (or increase) my lean body mass.
Given this, it seems to make sense to relate protein intake to lean body mass rather than body weight.
Any guidance in sizing this appreciated.

https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/29488/how-much-protein-should-i-be-eating and https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/792/protein-how-much-is-too-much use these numbers to calculate your protein intake based on your lean weight
